# Are CSS transitions possible for stateless React components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I did some research and from what I could gather, CSS transitions get applied during `componentDidMount`. Since a stateless component doesn't have any lifecycle methods, can CSS transitions work? I've tried using them with a functional component, and they are not working for me.

So I just want to verify that it's even possible, or if I have to make it into a stateful component. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would say `yes`!

When using stateless components, your current state/css should be based on the props passed in.

In a typical css example, you can toggle css transitions by adding or removing a class, adding/removing elements, etc.

Here's a basic example:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var element = document.querySelector('.divwithcolor');
  element.classList = element.classList.contains('amazingcolor') ? 'divwithcolor' : 'divwithcolor amazingcolor';
}
```

```css
.divwithcolor {
  color: darkblue;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.amazingcolor {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="divwithcolor">
  hello world!
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Change color</button>
```

In a realistic React example, you would have a parent component who's state changes and the render function is called. Your stateless component should be re-rendered with new props and this is where you would do your css transition.

Using the above example, you would just toggle the `amazingcolor` based on the props passed in.

Something like this:

```
...

var needsColor = this.props.isActive;
var colorClass = needsColor ? 'divwithcolor amazingcolor' : '';
return ( <div className="{colorClass}"> );

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible. Css trannsitions are possible for Stateless components too. Css properties get attached to stateless component when they are mounted. So the transitions handled using css will be active throughout the life time of the component.